# os-prober Doesn't Detect Windows 10 in Archlinux

Tags: arch-linux, grub2, uefi, grub2-mkconfig

I installed Arch recently (as in, yesterday). I was able to successfully install Grub in the EFI system Partition with `grub-install --target=x86_64-efi --efi-directory=/boot/efi --bootloader-id=grub --recheck`, `os-prober` and `grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg`.

After booting, though, I had two issues: First, I wanted grub to boot linux and not linux-lts kernel by default and second, I wanted it to select Windows by default and a timeout of 1s.

In the `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` file, I replaced three instances of linux-lts with linux in the first menuentry.

In the `/etc/default/grub` file, I set `GRUB_DEFAULT` as '`Windows Boot Manager on (/dev/nvme0n1p1)`' and `GRUB_TIMEOUT` as `1`.

When I ran `grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg`, it did not list Windows 10. Even when I ran `os-prober`, no results were shown.

On rebooting, Windows entry was not shown but timeout was 1s. So, what should I do? Thank you!

Comment: Did you read the wiki first? https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dual_boot_with_Windows

Comment: Yeah I did. So I should take help of ms_sys?

Comment: And how can I change the default kernel, too?

Comment: You need to write what exactly you did and what did not work for you.  Which step was the issue.

Comment: After installation, I did ```grub-install --target=x86_64-efi --efi-directory=/boot/efi --bootloader-id=grub --recheck```, where my system EFI partition was mounted as /boot/efi. Then ```os-prober``` and ```grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg```. This worked. Just when after rebooting I tried to change the default linux kernel, and did ```grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg```, it failed to recognize Windows. And ```os-prober``` also couldn't find windows.

Comment: Please do not put it into comment - it is **very** hard to read.  Edit you original question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok I installed ntfs-3g and ran o
`os-prober`. It detected Windows.